# check & update the Phonebook in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to update contact in the Phone Book but i need to check whether the contact no is under which head TYPE_WORK , TYPE_MOBILE etc....

```
 public void updateContact (String newNumber,String oldNumber)
            throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException {

        //ASSERT: @contactId alreay has a work phone number
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();


        String selectPhone = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  +
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "=?";

        String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{oldNumber, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)};

        if(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs).equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "MOBILE FIELD IS EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            phoneArgs = new String[]{oldNumber, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)};
            if(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs).equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Work FIELD IS EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Work FIELD IS NOT EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
                        .build());
            }
        }
        else {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
                    .build());
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
```

I tried Doing But Did not Succeed..PLs Help

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve both the contact id and contact type and use it in the update query arguments.I tried this and it worked. -

```
public void updateContact(String newNumber, String oldNumber) throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException {

    // get contact type and contact id
    String contactId = null;
    int contactType = -1;
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(oldNumber));
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            uri,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.TYPE},
            null,
            null,
            null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
            contactType = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.TYPE));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    //ASSERT: @contactId alreay has a work phone number
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();


    String selectPhone = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "=?";

    String[] phoneArgs = null;

    if (contactType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MOBILE FIELD IS EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        phoneArgs = new String[]{contactId, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)};
    } else if (contactType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Work FIELD IS EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        phoneArgs = new String[]{contactId, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)};
    }
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
            .build());


    ContentProviderResult[] contentProviderResults = this.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    if (contentProviderResults[0].count > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Updated Contact Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact could not be updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the permission to read and write contacts.
Hope this helps !